# Systematically generate Corner and Centered polygonal diagrams?

Tags: geometry, polygons

A [polygonal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number) is a number represented as dots or pebbles arranged in the shape of a regular polygon. Namely, it is "a type of figurate number which is a generalization of triangular, square, etc., numbers to an arbitrary n-gonal number".

The following diagrams taken from [mathworld.wolfram.com](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonalNumber.html) graphically illustrate the process by which the polygonal numbers are built up. We can call them the **Corner** polygonal numbers, (i.e. growing from the dot in the corner).

[image: Corner Polygonal Numbers]

Each of the above types of numbers has a cousin of sorts, which is called the [**Centered** polygonal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_polygonal_number). There each formed by a central dot (See the below diagrams).

[image: Centred Polygonal Numbers]

**Q: How to systematically generate the points (dots) arranged in the above Corner and Centered polygonal diagrams? Also the corresponding polygonal diagrams?**

one simple example for certered square, i.e. n=4 (maybe one can directly create `pts`):

```
n = 4; (*3: triangle; 4: square; etc*)
pts =Flatten[Table[{r*Sin[2 Pi k/n], r*Cos[2 Pi k/n]}, {k, n}, {r, 0.1, 0.3, 0.1}], 1];
pts1={{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}, {0.1, 0.2}, {0.2, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.1}, {-0.1, 0.2}, {-0.2, 0.1}, {0.1, -0.1}, {0.1, -0.2}, {0.2, -0.1}, {-0.1, -0.1}, {-0.1, -0.2}, {-0.2, -0.1}};
pts = Join[pts, pts1];
Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[pts]}]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### A very naïve approach

Let's use `RegularPolygon` (we could also use `CirclePoints`) with increasing radius. Then obtain its boundary and subdivide it.

```
subdivide[n_] := 
  Line[{p1_, p2_}] :> 
   With[{pts = Table[p1 + i (p2 - p1), {i, 0, 1, 1/n}]}, pts];

centeredPolygon[p_, r_] := 
  Join[MeshPrimitives[RegularPolygon[{r, 2 \[Pi]/p}, p], 1] /. 
    subdivide[r], {{{0, 0}}}];

corneredPolygon[p_, r_] := 
  MeshPrimitives[RegularPolygon[{-r, 0}, {r, 2 \[Pi]/p}, p], 1] /. 
   subdivide[r];


GraphicsRow[
 Table[Graphics[
   Table[{Line[#], {PointSize[.05], Point[#]}} & /@ 
     centeredPolygon[p, r], {r, 0, 4}]], {p, 3, 7}]]

GraphicsRow[
 Table[Graphics[
   Table[{Line[#], {PointSize[.05], Point[#]}} & /@ 
     corneredPolygon[p, r], {r, 0, 4}]], {p, 3, 7}]]
```

#### Centered Polygons

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Cornered Polygons

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: that's a very nice way to do it with `RegularPolygon`, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Here's another approach using [`AnglePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnglePath):

```
cornerPath[n_, div_] := With[{s = Pi - (n-2)/(2n) Pi, a = Pi - (n-2)/n Pi},
    AnglePath @ If[div==0,
        PadRight[{s}, n, a],
        Riffle[ConstantArray[0, n div], PadRight[{s}, n, a], {1, -2, div+1}]
    ]
]

centerPath[n_, div_] := TranslationTransform[{(div+1)/(2 Cos[(n-2)/(2n) Pi]), 0}] @ cornerPath[n, div]
```

Examples:

```
Graphics[{
    PointSize[Large],
    Table[Through @ {Point, Line} @ cornerPath[4, n], {n, 0, 3}]
}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{
    PointSize[Large],
    Point[{0, 0}], 
    Table[Through @ {Point, Line} @ centerPath[5, n], {n, 0, 3}]
}]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! that's very helpful